# Best way to go about wiping and installing most recent version of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, upgrade, reinstall

There is a computer that has been sitting in our lab office that nobody has used in +8 years. It's running Ubuntu 14.04.

I've been trying to download some useful software to it, but I've run into a lot of issues with python packages and different things not working.. possibly because of how old this version of Ubuntu is, or issues with what is already installed on it, which I had no part in doing. It tried updating a lot of things the first time I logged onto it, and ultimately I had to revert all of the updates because it no longer worked and got stuck in a login loop.

At this point, there is nothing worth saving on this computer, and I would really like to just delete everything and install a newer version of Ubuntu to start from scratch with. Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: Download and install.... applies if it's a new computer, old computer, new drive, old drive with existing OS (regardless of what's on it, be it windows, ubuntu, BSD or anything else)... https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview

Comment: Other tutorials exist on the tutorial site too; eg. validating a downloaded ISO prior to write to media - https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 , writing the downloaded ISO to thumb-drive https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview
https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview
inc. writing to DVD & other media too if needed.

Comment: Confirm the old computer meets minimum spec's before spending time trying to install an OS on it., 32bit vs 64bit, UEFI, RAM, disk space, etc.  Make sure the articles you choose to read are newer that the version of Ubuntu you select, Old articles are mostly useless, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements